# MySQL 3306 open port security

Tags: mysql, ports

I know that having the MySQL 3306 port is unsafe even if you restrict the user access based on IP. But what if you really need remote access to your database ? Maybe two applications reading and updating data at the same time.

If we have two applications one on the same host as the database and another one remote what would be a viable and secure way of sharing the same data ? Should we host the database some other place ? Should we have two local databases for each application and keep them up-to-date ? What would you suggest ?

Comment: You can restrict it with firewalls, which can be dedicated boxes or operating system firewall.

Comment: If I use a CSF Firewall for example to restrict the port wouldn't that also restrict my remote application from creating a connection ?

Comment: Yes, unless you explicitly allow the remote application's IP to connect (and deny all others). But it is the wrong solution to apply IMO-- now you are entirely dependent on your network admin for your application security, and one errant change to the firewall config can leave you wide open. Or it can interrupt your application.

Comment: I understand what you mean. At the moment I am both the developer and the network admin so it should not be a problem. Still it might cause problems in the future.

Comment: Just to beat a dead horse, I strongly recommend against going the firewall route. The above problem aside, the traffic to/from your DB is also unencrypted-- any DB requests traveling across the internet can be read in clear text. But if you use a VPN or SSH tunnel, it's all encrypted.

Comment: For the MySQL the firewall is good choice because exposing MySQL port is risky. So to reduce the attack surface and understanding the multi-layered nature of the security, the firewall needs to be used. There are several risk associated with open MySQL ports and using firewall to do it is good way. The monitoring of firewall rules and testing the open ports is not the scope of securing the MySQL, it is the scope of the infrastructure.

Comment: The VPN is not suitable solution for accessing MySQL, there are many issues associated with it including cloud. The problem is that Database and Applications are tightly coupled so therefore they both require low latency and high availability. So this way if you use VPN you will need two VPNs via two different routes to two availability zones to make it stable, this is for sure true for AWS. SSH tunnels and most VPNs doesn't deliver performance and stability for Application-Database performance since the tunnel is just single connection and it's not managed as it should be for db.

Comment: The best solution is to have database close without VPN but just VLAN and you can setup replication. However if it's master-master replication this won't work well if it's not the same VLAN as it depends on low or at least stable latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options. If your applications are in a cloud environment, setup an internal network connection between the two. If this is available to you, go with this.

You could setup a VPN connection between the two machines, which is quite secure, but requires some configuration. Another, (in my opinion better) option would be to use a SSH tunnel or variants (SSL tunnel).

Answer (score 2):

Set up a VPN between both machines.

Comment: Or, if budget is an issue, set up a persistent SSH tunnel. see also: autossh.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions, I have researched a little bit on both but  I wanted to know what other people would suggest. You made a good point regarding the budget.

Answer (score 0):

As said by other users, an alternative is a VPN connection. But for answer completion, a poor man alternative cloud be a SSH port forward.

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 someuser@someserver.com
```

Just connect to your localhost:3306 and enjoy your mysql connection. But remember to only allow the connection for trusted hosts, or, if is a database that is only used by localhost, bind it to 127.0.0.1.